# How to acces a jQuery variable in html

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a 2-D array(`_BgtArray`) which i have passed into my view. i want to display specific array values on mouseover. i have passed paired values as id (like 00,01,02,10,11,12 and so on..).
The mouseover function is something like this:

**jQuery:**

```
 $('.Cell').hover(function (e) {
                var row = $(this).attr('id').substr(0, 1);
                var column = $(this).attr('id').substr(1, 2);
                $('div#pop-up').html("Budget Allocated: @Model._BgtArray[row,column]");
                $('div#pop-up').show();
        }, function () {
            $('div#pop-up').hide();
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<td class="Cell" id="@k@i" > // k and i are loop variables
              *Some text here*
         </td>
```

@Model._BgtArray[row,column] gives me an error. Although I am quite aware that we cant use jQuery variables this way, i am not able to find a proper solution for this. Can you please suggest a way?

Comment: A couple things to note with your solution/logic. 

 1. You can not call a razor variable in a separate file - it must be in the same view. Not sure if this is what you're doing, but it won't work if you are.
 2. Using this solution is not separating the UI from the behavior(s) which may or may not be an issue later as you expand on this. Also, I don't see where you're setting @k or @i. What is this error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways of skinning this cat. One way would be to attach a specific event handler for each cell nother would be to construct a JS array from you model. The latter is the simplest. You'd only need a few changes.

```
 //initialize array based on your model. E.g. in a for loop or a foreach
 var budget = ...;

 $('.Cell').hover(function () {
                var row = $(this).attr('id').substr(0, 1);
                var column = $(this).attr('id').substr(1, 2);
                $('div#pop-up').text("Budget Allocated: " + budget[row]column]");
                $('div#pop-up').show();
        }, function () {
            $('div#pop-up').hide();
        });
```